# what configuration do I need to change for 'ng build --prod' to find files outside of angular cli working folder structure

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I changed the folder structure of my angular project.  before I changed the folder structure, 'ng build --prod' worked correctly.

After changing the folder structure (and adding paths to tsconfig.spec.json and tsconfig.app.json) I am able to run 'ng serve' 'ng test' and 'ng build', but I cannot successfully run 'ng build --prod'.

Before changing the folder structure, the project was created using angular cli and the 'ng new' command. The folder structure was like this:

[image: before changing folder structure]

After changing the folder structure, the project looks like this:

[image: after changing folder structure]

Now, running 'ng build --prod', I get this error:

ERROR in Ui/src/$$_gendir/app/queues/review-queue/review-queue.component.ngfactory.ts (12,21): Cannot find module '../../../../../../CommonUi/src/app/queues/queues-datatable/queues-datatable.component.ngfactory'.

what configuration do I need to change for 'ng build --prod' to find ngfactory files outside of the standard angular cli folder structure.

Comment: Sorry, but one of the things about Angular (and webpack projects specific) is that all your items for a single project are contained inside one directory. You can either copy-paste the items you need into your currect project, or restructure your project to be one level up and include _everything_ in both.

Answer (score -1):

Angular 6 now has the idea of a Library.   The Angular Library can solve this problem.  Nrwl.io can solve this problem as well using their idea of a monorepo for Angular projects.   https://nrwl.io/